# No puedo llegar al controlador dede ajax en C#.Net con Entity Framework

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, .net, entity-framework

Estoy intentando enviar datos al controlador desde ajax a c#.Net con mvc y entity framework , pero lamentablemente no puedo ingresar a él.
he intentado de todo pero no ingresa, incluso los datos si viajan pero no entra al controlador.

este es mi código.

Código cshtml

```
@model AgendaCsharpEntity.Models.usuarioCuenta

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Agregar";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Agregar</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>usuarioCuenta</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idUsuarioCuenta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idUsuarioCuenta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idUsuarioCuenta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombreUsuarioCuenta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nombreUsuarioCuenta,new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            <input type="text" id="nom" class="form-control col-md-2" value="nommmmm">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombreUsuarioCuenta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.contrasenaUsuarioCuenta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.contrasenaUsuarioCuenta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            <input type="text" id="pass" class="form-control col-md-2">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.contrasenaUsuarioCuenta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.emailUsuarioCuenta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.emailUsuarioCuenta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control col-md-2">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emailUsuarioCuenta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descripcionUsuarioCuenta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.descripcionUsuarioCuenta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            <input type="text" id="desc" class="form-control col-md-2">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descripcionUsuarioCuenta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tipoUsuarioCuenta, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.tipoUsuarioCuenta, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            <input type="text" id="tipoCuenta" class="form-control col-md-2">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tipoUsuarioCuenta, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idUsuario, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.idUsuario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idUsuario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            <button type="button" id="btnCreate" value="Crear" class="btn btn-default">Crear</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Código jquery

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnCreate').click(function (e) {


    var nombre = $("#nom").val();
    var pass = $("#pass").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var descr = $("#desc").val();
    var tipo = $("#tipoCuenta").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Cuentas/Agregar',
        data:
        {
            nom: nombre,
            passw: pass,
            em: email,
            descri: descr,
            tpo: tipo
        },
        //cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error in GetUnitDateRangeParamsVals.1');
        }
    });
});
 });

</script>
```

Código c# , controlador

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Agregar(string nombre, string pass, string email, string desc, string tipo) 
    {
        using(agendaEntities db= new agendaEntities()) 
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    usuarioCuenta uc = new usuarioCuenta();
                    uc.nombreUsuarioCuenta = nombre;
                    uc.contrasenaUsuarioCuenta = pass;
                    uc.emailUsuarioCuenta = email;
                    uc.descripcionUsuarioCuenta = desc;
                    uc.tipoUsuarioCuenta = tipo;
                    db.usuarioCuenta.Add(uc);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error" + ex.Message);
                    return View();
                    throw;

                }
            }




        }

    }
```

En la consola me manda al error en ves de entrar al controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan da error 500 , y los parámetros si los estoy enviando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor su ayuda.
gracias.

Comment: En la pestaña network, ahí donde ves que es error 500, también existe una pestaña que dice "Response". Qué dice?

Comment: me aparece lo siguiente : [[HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The required anti-forgery form field &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present.]
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken) +172
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext) +159
   System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate() +141
   System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +116

Comment: Bueno. Ahí está tu respuesta. Estás haciendo un post y el método del post tiene un atributo `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` que se encarga de verificar que el post no viene de alguna otra fuente, sino que es legítimo. En tu vista tienes `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. Debes incluir ese valor en tu llamada `$.ajax`

Comment: y como podria capturar ese valor para pasarselo por ajax? ya que biene por razor = @Html.AntiForgeryToken() ?

Comment: Prueba a renombrar el data que estas enviando; me refiero a que los campos se llamen igual que en tu controlador (nom = nombre, em = email, etc)

Comment: ok lo acabo de hacer pero igual sigue el error, y en el data por ejemplo como le paso el @Html.AntiForgeryToken() ya que ese biene por razor no biene en una etiqueta html como para capturarla con un id

Comment: **¿Cómo hacerlo?** ya es otra pregunta. Prueba editar esta pregunta e indicarnos lo que has intentado.

Comment: @SimónPereiraVigouroux asegurate de borrar la cache de tu navegador antes de probar, a veces eso juega malas pasadas

Comment: Además me surge la duda, de porque estas enviando datos por ajax, si al utilizar Razor puedes especificar en el mismo Form a que controlador y a que accion se debe enviar los datos no?

Comment: Si pero me dijeron que ese era el problema es por ello que consulto como poder pasar ese valor al ajax y asi el error desaparecera

Comment: Si lo qeu pasa es que habia creado el proyecto pero lo cambie para poder hacer las peticiones asincronas, y si te fijas en el formulario le puse inputs html con sus respectivos id, los cuales los capturo en el codigo jquery para luego enviarlos por ajax

Comment: Pero también puedes crear método asíncronos en tu controlador, por eso encuentro innecesario utilizar ajax al usar Razor; deben haber excepciones puntuales obviamente, pero ya al utilizar Razor deberías saltarte ajax para _submitear_ tus datos hacia el controller

Comment: OK es que bueno aun me falta aprender mas de ajax y también de .net y bueno en un trabajo que tuve se trabajaba ajax en las vistas y desde ajax enviaban al controlador, esa es la manera en la cual trabaje ajax, pero bueno vere la manera de resolverlo . gracias.

Comment: Por cierto, el `AntiForgeryToken` sí viene en una etiqueta. Búsca un `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"/>`

Comment: @SimónPereiraVigouroux de todas formas mira [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663762/mvc-ajax-post-to-controller-action-method) pregunta/respuesta, puede que estes fallando en la forma en que estas enviando los datos hacia el controlador, ya que la estructura y los tipos deben concordar con lo que recibe tu controller

Comment: Hola buenas ya lo corregi , solo quite [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] de razor de la vista y tambien lo quite del controlador ya hora entra al controlador sin problemas, pero mi duda es si es importante que [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] esté presente en el controlador? será conveniente quitarlo?

Comment: Respuesta corta: **No es conveniente quitarlo**. Respuesta larga: Ese token es la forma en que el framework "Firma" el form renderizado, y verifica su validez una vez es "submitted". Quitarlo es una gran irresponsabilidad y deja tu sitio vulnerable a muchos tipos de ataques.

Comment: mmmm entiendo entonces debo ver la manera de pasarlo por ajax si o si

Comment: Tal vez [esta respuesta te ayude.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc#:~:text=In%20Asp.Net%20MVC%20when,so%20it%20can%20be%20validated.)

Comment: Muchas gracias , ahora si puedo enviar los datos sin tener que quitar [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]. muchas gracias.